# LaTeX item subheading problem

Tags: sharelatex

Hello please check the following document: https://www.overleaf.com/read/sgtfdrbhzrkb .

Code:

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Sourabh Bajaj
% Website: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{%
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\

    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{\href{http://ipaul.ro/}{\Large Paul Ionescu}} & Email : \href{mailto:paulionescu@icloud.com}{paulionescu@icloud.com}\\
  \href{http://ipaul.ro/}{http://ipaul.ro/} & Mobile : +40-741-126-510 \\
\end{tabular*}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Technical University of Civil Engineering of Bucharest}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Master of Science in Structural Engineering; G: 9.80/10.00}{Oct. 2016 -- July 2018}
      {Dissertation topic: Applications of Neural Networks in Civil Engineering}

    \resumeSubheading
      {École Spéciale des Travaux Publics, du bâtiment et de l'industrie (ESTP)}{Paris, France}
      {Erasmus+ Exchange Student;  G: 14.23/20.00)}{Sep. 2015 -- Mar. 2016}

    \resumeSubheading
      {Technical University of Civil Engineering of Bucharest}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Bachelor of Science in Civil Engineering;  G: 9.80/10.00}{Oct. 2012 -- July 2016}

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {\href{http://over4.org/}{Over4.org}}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Structural Engineer}{Sep. 2017 - Present}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Sustainable design NGO}
          {TensorFlow is an open source software library for numerical computation using data flow graphs; primarily used for training deep learning models.}
        \resumeItem{SDE2019}
          {Solar Decathlon Europe is an International competition that challenges collegiate teams to design and build houses powered exclusively by the renewable energy sources. We have qualified for the 2019 edition, the main topic consisting of solutions aimed at the renovation of the existing building stock}
      \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {Interactive Design}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Structural Engineer}{Jan. 2017 - Present}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Tensorflow}
          {TensorFlow is an open source software library for numerical computation using data flow graphs; primarily used for training deep learning models.}
        \resumeItem{Apache Beam}
          {Apache Beam is a unified model for defining both batch and streaming data-parallel processing pipelines, as well as a set of language-specific SDKs for constructing pipelines and runners.}
      \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {Ministry of Internal Affairs}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Civil Engineer Intern}{Jul. 2016 - Sep. 2016}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Notifications}
          {Service for sending email, push and in-app notifications. Involved in features such as delivery time optimization, tracking, queuing and A/B testing. Built an internal app to run batch campaigns for marketing etc.}
        \resumeItem{Nostos}
          {Bulk data processing and injection service from Hadoop to Cassandra and provides a thin REST layer on top for serving offline computed data online.}
        \resumeItem{Workflows}
          {Dataduct an open source workflow framework to create and manage data pipelines leveraging reusables patterns to expedite developer productivity.}
        \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {QAFCO (Qatar Fertilizer Company)}{Doha, Qatar}
      {Civil Engineer Intern}{Aug. 2015 - Sep. 2015}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Tensorflow}
          {TensorFlow is an open source software library for numerical computation using data flow graphs; primarily used for training deep learning models.}
        \resumeItem{Apache Beam}
          {Apache Beam is a unified model for defining both batch and streaming data-parallel processing pipelines, as well as a set of language-specific SDKs for constructing pipelines and runners.}
      \resumeItemListEnd

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-----------PROJECTS-----------------
\section{Projects}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubItem{QuantSoftware Toolkit}
      {Open source python library for financial data analysis and machine learning for finance.}
    \resumeSubItem{Github Visualization}
      {Data Visualization of Git Log data using D3 to analyze project trends over time.}
    \resumeSubItem{Recommendation System}
      {Music and Movie recommender systems using collaborative filtering on public datasets.}
%     \resumeSubItem{Mac Setup}
%       {Book that gives step by step instructions on setting up developer environment on Mac OS.}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%
%--------PROGRAMMING SKILLS------------
\section{Programming Skills}
 \resumeSubHeadingListStart
   \item{
     \textbf{Languages}{: Python, Matlab, C++, Ansys APDL}
     \hfill
     \textbf{Machine Learning}{}
   }
 \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

I am a begineer trying to use a template and I encounter an error when I am adding another subheading.
Look for the markups in this picture: [image]
The issue is the line Dissertation topic... that looks akward in contrast with the previous.
Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Remove `\vspace{-5pt}` at the end of the definition of `\resumeSubheading`.

Comment: also `\item\small{...}` makes the rest of the enumeration small, not just the things in the `{...}`  But please post example code not external links or screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the missing space just comment the both `\vspace` commands in your code:

```
\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{%
% \vspace{-1pt}%
  \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\

    \end{tabular*}%
%   \vspace{-5pt}
}
```

SO with the following MWE (please see the changed order of called packages!)

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Sourabh Bajaj
% Website: https://github.com/sb2nov/resume
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{%
% \vspace{-1pt}%
  \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\

    \end{tabular*}%
%   \vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{\href{http://ipaul.ro/}{\Large Paul Ionescu}} & Email : \href{mailto:paulionescu@icloud.com}{paulionescu@icloud.com}\\
  \href{http://ipaul.ro/}{http://ipaul.ro/} & Mobile : +40-741-126-510 \\
\end{tabular*}


%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Technical University of Civil Engineering of Bucharest}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Master of Science in Structural Engineering; G: 9.80/10.00}{Oct. 2016 -- July 2018}
      {Dissertation topic: Applications of Neural Networks in Civil Engineering}

    \resumeSubheading
      {École Spéciale des Travaux Publics, du bâtiment et de l'industrie (ESTP)}{Paris, France}
      {Erasmus+ Exchange Student;  G: 14.23/20.00)}{Sep. 2015 -- Mar. 2016}

    \resumeSubheading
      {Technical University of Civil Engineering of Bucharest}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Bachelor of Science in Civil Engineering;  G: 9.80/10.00}{Oct. 2012 -- July 2016}

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart

    \resumeSubheading
      {\href{http://over4.org/}{Over4.org}}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Structural Engineer}{Sep. 2017 - Present}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Sustainable design NGO}
          {TensorFlow is an open source software library for numerical computation using data flow graphs; primarily used for training deep learning models.}
        \resumeItem{SDE2019}
          {Solar Decathlon Europe is an International competition that challenges collegiate teams to design and build houses powered exclusively by the renewable energy sources. We have qualified for the 2019 edition, the main topic consisting of solutions aimed at the renovation of the existing building stock}
      \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {Interactive Design}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Structural Engineer}{Jan. 2017 - Present}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Tensorflow}
          {TensorFlow is an open source software library for numerical computation using data flow graphs; primarily used for training deep learning models.}
        \resumeItem{Apache Beam}
          {Apache Beam is a unified model for defining both batch and streaming data-parallel processing pipelines, as well as a set of language-specific SDKs for constructing pipelines and runners.}
      \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {Ministry of Internal Affairs}{Bucharest, Romania}
      {Civil Engineer Intern}{Jul. 2016 - Sep. 2016}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Notifications}
          {Service for sending email, push and in-app notifications. Involved in features such as delivery time optimization, tracking, queuing and A/B testing. Built an internal app to run batch campaigns for marketing etc.}
        \resumeItem{Nostos}
          {Bulk data processing and injection service from Hadoop to Cassandra and provides a thin REST layer on top for serving offline computed data online.}
        \resumeItem{Workflows}
          {Dataduct an open source workflow framework to create and manage data pipelines leveraging reusables patterns to expedite developer productivity.}
        \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {QAFCO (Qatar Fertilizer Company)}{Doha, Qatar}
      {Civil Engineer Intern}{Aug. 2015 - Sep. 2015}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Tensorflow}
          {TensorFlow is an open source software library for numerical computation using data flow graphs; primarily used for training deep learning models.}
        \resumeItem{Apache Beam}
          {Apache Beam is a unified model for defining both batch and streaming data-parallel processing pipelines, as well as a set of language-specific SDKs for constructing pipelines and runners.}
      \resumeItemListEnd

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-----------PROJECTS-----------------
\section{Projects}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubItem{QuantSoftware Toolkit}
      {Open source python library for financial data analysis and machine learning for finance.}
    \resumeSubItem{Github Visualization}
      {Data Visualization of Git Log data using D3 to analyze project trends over time.}
    \resumeSubItem{Recommendation System}
      {Music and Movie recommender systems using collaborative filtering on public datasets.}
%     \resumeSubItem{Mac Setup}
%       {Book that gives step by step instructions on setting up developer environment on Mac OS.}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%
%--------PROGRAMMING SKILLS------------
\section{Programming Skills}
 \resumeSubHeadingListStart
   \item{
     \textbf{Languages}{: Python, Matlab, C++, Ansys APDL}
     \hfill
     \textbf{Machine Learning}{}
   }
 \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

you get the following result:

[image]